# Taipy adjust height in chart

Tags: python, user-interface, charts, dashboard, taipy

I want to create a layout for the charts as below. Could you provide me with a sample of this case?

[charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4qiM.png)

I adjusted the attribute "Height" inside the chart; no changes were made to my layout.

<|{data}|chart|x=x_col|y[1]=y_col_1|y[2]=y_col_2|type[1]=bar|height=200|>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the heights, you have to add px/%/em.
<{data}|chart|x=x_col|y[1]=y_col_1|y[2]=y_col_2|type[1]=bar|height=600px|>

Here is the way to achieve the graph layout.

```
<|layout|columns=1 1|

<|{data}|chart|x=x_col|y[1]=y_col_1|y[2]=y_col_2|type[1]=bar|height=600px|>

<|
<|{data}|chart|x=x_col|y[1]=y_col_1|y[2]=y_col_2|height=300px|type[1]=bar|>
<|{data}|chart|x=x_col|y[1]=y_col_1|y[2]=y_col_2|type[1]=bar|height=300px|>
<|{data}|chart|x=x_col|y[1]=y_col_1|y[2]=y_col_2|type[1]=bar|height=300px|>
|>

|>
```